# Безымянные программы в автозагрузке

Tags: windows, автозагрузка, windows-11, диспетчер-задач

## Описание

Недавно, непонятно откуда, появились вот такие программы в автозагрузке:

[image]

Нету у них ни информации, ни издателя, ни расположения:

[image]

Думаю, вы догадались, что я не знаю - откуда они появились. Ладно у последнего хотя бы имя есть, но 2 программы с именем "Program" найти вообще беда. В программы и компоненты они тоже отсутствуют...

[image]

Все мне известные локации автозагрузки тоже не хранят их.
Проверил позавчера антивирусом EsetNod, после 100% сканирования говорит, что даже подозрительных программ нету.

## Вопрос

Тогда что это такое? Где мне их найти, или же как удалить (не только из автозагрузки)?

Comment: В реестре по путям `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` и `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` смотрели?

Comment: @ZxNuClear В первый не смотрел. Сейчас удалил там 2 значения и пропали Wondershare и один из Program. Но второй в этих разделах отсутствует.

Comment: @ZxNuClear вы дали мне идею. Посмотрел во всех разделах Run в реестре. Там ещё были копии какие-то этого Wondershare. Удалил их всех и второй тоже пропал. Спасибо.

Comment: На будущее, на такой случай есть крайне полезная утилита Autoruns - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: @Yaant спасибо, учту.